# How to add trainable parameters into Tensorflow2 Keras model loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train an image denoiser network with Keras (Tensorflow2). For the loss function, I want to use something like (**a1** * L1_loss + **a2** * L2_loss), where **a1** and **a2** is trainable, which means after I gave them initial valuse, they can get updated each training iteration. But I am stuck here for a while and do know how should I implement this.

Here is some example code,

```
model_input = Input(shape=self.input_shape)
l1_weight = tf.Variable(0.5, trainable=True, name='L1_Loss_weight')
l2_weight = tf.Variable(0.5, trainable=True, name='L2_Loss_weight')
model_output= Conv3D(filters=self.filters, kernel_size=self.kernel_size, padding='same')(model_input)

self.model = Model(inputs=model_input,
                   outputs=model_output)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD()
model_loss = mixed_loss(L1_weight=l1_weight, L2_weight=l2_weight)
self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                   loss=model_loss)
```

where my loss function is defined as

```
def mixed_loss(L1_weight, L2_weight):
    def mixed(y_true, y_pred):
        return L1_weight * mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred) + L2_weight * mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
    return mixed
```

And then I use fit() function to pass the tf.data.Dataset, which including the training data, to do the training.

Although I can add two weights parameters this way, these weights are un-trainable and they wouldn't change as training. Really hope to get some hints or examples if anyone has some ideas about this problem. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you want to update them? The rest of the weights are updated as `dL/dw` where L is the Loss function.

Comment: I supoose it's just like conventional ML but there are some more trainable weights in loss function `L`, let's say `a1 / a2`, so that the loss function can be writhen as `L(a1, a2)` .Then the update for `a1` or `a2` can be the same with any other weights `w` that do backpropagation following `dL/da`. @AniketBote